# React Native - Make a view appear and follow screen after user scroll down enough, view apear and disappear too slow

Tags: android, react-native, react-hooks, scrollview

I have a button that appear after user have scrolled down enough on a long screen that is contained in a ScrollView, I have some code for it and it works, however the view take a full second to appear and disappear and that's too slow! Is there anyway to make it appear and disappear faster?

```
const [showBottomButton, setShowBottomButton] = useState(false)
```

.

```
const  handleScroll = (event) => {
        var curY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
            if (curY>=500 && !showBottomButton){
                setShowBottomButton(true)
            }else if (curY<500 && showBottomButton){
                setShowBottomButton(false)
            }
    }
```

.

```
{showBottomButton ? <View style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, height: 70, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white', borderTopWidth: 1, borderColor: '#eeeeee' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={BottomButtonOnpress}>
                    <View style={styles.BottomButton}
                        <Text style={styles.MediumText}>Button Text</Text>
                    </View></TouchableOpacity>
            </View> : null}
```